# Sax parser replaces "\n" by "\\n"

Tags: java, xml, sax

I'm parsing a XML-file with the SAX parser from org.xml.sax. I've implemented nothing more than the `startElement` and `endElement` methods.

Sometimes lines like `"text text \n text"` need to be parsed.

The parser transforms them to `"text text \\n text"`. I don't want that. Is it possible to stop the parser from doing such adjustments without manipulating the string myself?

I checked the api for the Defaulthandler class, but didn't find anything.

Best Ricardo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string

```
"text text \n text"
```

contains the two character `\n` which in your XML are **not** the newline character. If the XML parser would just pass these two characters as is, the result would contain a newline where none is in the input.

Escaping the `\n` to `\\n` is the corect thing to do.

Comment: I understand that this behaviour is somehow reasonable, its just not what I want. I now change it afterwards by hand. Thank you.